# LinearLayout horizontal exceeds small screen

Tags: android, width, screen, android-linearlayout

I have two DatePickers, side by side.
It works good on larger screen, but when I run my application on smaller devices, I only see the first one, the other is truncated.

I'd like the second DatePicker being drown at the bottom of the first one when there's no enough space on the screen.

Is it possible avoiding programmatically ways and do it in the XML file?

This is the fragment of my code. It's nested in another LinearLayout.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/date_start"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:calendarViewShown="false" />

        <DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/date_end"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:calendarViewShown="false" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a folder `layout-large` in `res` and move this code there. Then you can change this code to be how you want on a smaller screen. When on larger screens your app will use the `layout-large` and use the `layout` folder when on smaller screens

You would simply need to change this code to use an `orientation` of `vertical` and maybe adjust some other properties depending on how it will look on smaller screens.

[Using Layout qualifiers](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers)

Just an FYI, `LinearLayout` has an `orientation` of `horizontal` by default so that property isn't needed but doesn't hurt, either. I just like to point that out because it may be useful to know in the future.

Comment: I hoped there was a way to do it dinamically with specific attributes in only one layout file. But this solution work perfectly, thx!

Comment: Nope and you can't change your xml at runtime so this is the way to go. Plus it will be useful if you have other `layout`s with similar problems. Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

You can use a FlowLayout, it is not a sdk default, but someone already developed it, take a look:
https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout