# Titanium Android - How to differentiate between a smaptphone and a tablet?

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile, screen-resolution

I'm using Titanium SDK 2.1.3 and I've come across this problem recently, since Android 4.0 and greater can be found in both smartphones and tablets, how can I differentiate between them? If I try to distinguish based on resolutions it wouldn't work right, since some high end smartphones have smaller screens but higher screen resolutions, while some tablets have bigger screens but smaller resolutions.

The app I'm working on work should be displayed in portrait on smartphones, in the case of tablets it should be shown in landscape.

What's the right approach to differentiate between a tablet and a smartphone?
Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: [Check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17366549/linearlayout-horizontal-exceeds-small-screen/17366589#17366589)

Comment: "The app I'm working on work should be displayed in portrait on smartphones, in the case of tablets it should be shown in landscape" -- in your users' opinions, it should be displayed in both portrait and landscape on all device sizes. Please minimize the number of activities that prevent the user from using their device the way they want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a module that calculates the screen size of the device based on the number of pixels per inch, though not 100% accurate it works, this is [the link](https://github.com/skypanther/ScreenSizes/blob/master/Resources/tablet.js)